# Why is the review in Stack Overflow so strict?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

Why is the review on Stack Overflow  so strict?

I only made one incorrect review and already got banned.

(Image took from last time). Now I have to wait for 8 days...

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, you missed that [this is spam](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15601586).

Prior to that you missed that [this is also spam](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15579562).

Before that one, you missed that [this is vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15541327). Failing suggested-edit audits is pretty bad; those are just random text crammed into a post, so they're pretty blatantly wrong.

Then before that you [missed this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15515373).

...there were a couple of other ones before that too, but you get the idea. That's all just *this month*.

Slow down, spend some extra time reading and considering the post you're looking at, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm curious as what made you think that you only made one mistake. Is it UI issue?

Comment: @justhalf My bet is on cognitive dissonance ...